# Exception when try to save() product from cron job

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have a cron job to set product price dynamically.

If I set price by below code then product view page display updated price but updated price not showing on listing page for product :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId()->load($product_id);
$Price = $dynamic;
$_product->setPrice($Price)->getResource()->saveAttribute($_product, 'price');
```

When I used below code then getting exception :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId()->load($product_id);
$Price = $dynamic;
$_product->setPrice($Price);
$_product->save();
```

Exception is :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2207-0-3-0' for key 'CC12C83765B562314470A24F2BDD0F36', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_group_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `value`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' in /home/cityretails/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348 Stack trace: #0 /home/cityretails/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[23000]...') #1 /home/cityretails/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[23000]...') #2 /home/cityretails/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1660): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterSa...', Array) #3 /home/cityretails/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product.php(195): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract in /home/cityretails/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1348
```

While when I save product from admin it saved successfully.
And after save product updated price showing on listing page.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: provide full code then we will able to judge what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code add store as admin and let me know

```
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $_product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $Price = $dynamic;
    $_product->setPrice($Price);
    $_product->save();
```

Comment: If its help you then mark as accepted, so other users also take benefit from it